# How to add UITableView to UIView which is already a subview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have specific situation for which I haven't found solution.
I'm doing over storyboard. So I have `ViewController` on which I'm using segment control for switching subviews. Every subview is `ViewController` but one of them is using `table view`. So basically it's like this:

**HomeViewController**

- `FavoritesViewController`

  - `Table View` (with custom cell)
- `GalleryViewController`

How to properly set up this? Should I rename/refunction `FavoritesViewController` to `FavoritesTableViewController` or?

If there is any other question, please ask it.

**UPDATE 1:**
FavoritesViewController is having just UIView in UI because I don't need whole UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

Create an IBAction from the segmented control. Inside the handling method, use "ViewController containment" to switch between two view controllers.